# Как принудительно заврешить приложение с ошибкой

Tags: android

Как сделать, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку приложение вылетало с ошибкой? Но приложение естественно должно успешно компилироваться.

Comment: Подели на ноль )

Comment: Мне бы небольшой кодик. уже час парюсь =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

Answer (score 10):

- аккуратно разделить на ноль (что бы компилятор не догадался)
- попытаться прочитать несуществующий файл
- разыменовать null-ссылку
- работать с сетью с main thread (для 4 андроида)
- Сгенерировать исключение явно
- рекурсивно запустить метод
- в цикле (или рекурсивно) выделять память (например, создавая объекты)
- вызвать метод, который требует более высокого "api level", чем предоставляет телефон/планшет (это уже более специфично для андроид)
- вызвать нативный код, который сделает все сам :)
- что либо долго делать в главном потоке. через 3-5 секунд система предложить прибить приложение (классический ANR - Application not Responding)
- зайти на Stackoverflow, ввести [android fc](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+fc) и выбирать:) (FC - Force close - неожиданное завершение).

Comment: > вызвать нативный код, который сделает все сам :)

Всмысле?

Comment: Полагаю, что-то вроде

    int *p = 0;
    *p = 0;

Comment: в прямом. нативный код - это код на С/С++, который вызывается через jni. В с/с++ возможностей отстрелить ногу на порядок больше. Хотя можно попробовать положить so'шку-пустышку (или вообще ничего не  добавлять), но с кода вызывать. То есть, просто объявить метод с словом `native`.

Answer (score 3):

```
throw new Exception()
```

Answer (score 1):

Создай массив на 2 элемента и обратись к 3-ему.